# How Do I Change Firefox Homepage In VB Code

Tags: vb.net, firefox, url

How Do I Change Firefox Homepage In VB2011 Code

I want to change the url homepage of the firefox browser by running that EXE file

is this possible

Comment: I doubt this is possible, consider the security risks. As a suprise it might be, your user might not want your application to be his home page. Also, SO is for learning, not just copy pasting.

Comment: @TJH: Why on Earth would it not be possible to change the homepage?

Comment: @Tim: We thought he was trying to change the user's home page from an ASP.NET page, it was ambiguous.

Comment: @Albireo: Sorry, I should have checked the revision history!

Comment: My bad actually, i was thinking vbscript for web somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the Firefox's home page form a program running on the user's computer, you have to edit the [`prefs.js`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/A_Brief_Guide_to_Mozilla_Preferences) file and create a new line like `user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://www.example.com/");`.

Beware that if there are multiple `browser.startup.homepage` entries every entry will be opened in a new tab when the browser starts up, and that the modification must be done when Firefox is closed, otherwise the changes will be lost.

Comment: when i install Nero(cd burner) it changes my Defaut browser's url homepage as www.ask.com......

Comment: @Vignesh: Changed the answer to reflect the clarification.

Comment: @Albiero Thanks man ... but i read it in one site..... i want VB programme to change that

Comment: @Vignesh: Open the file for writing, append the line, save the file, where's the problem?