# How to change browsers home page through VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, firefox, browser

I add this code to prefs.js file:

```
user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://www.google.com/");
```

It doesn't work. Firefox opens the usual page.

Comment: People are capable of setting thier own homepage, consequently many browsers block javascript from setting it. It may be possible, but its not a good idea

Comment: may be you can check [This][1]


it may help you 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107952/how-do-i-change-firefox-homepage-in-vb-code

Answer (score 0):

Add BookMark it Link to your website using JavaScript

function setHomepage() {

//Condition to set home page in IE

if (document.all) {

document.body.style.behavior = 'url(#default#homepage)';

document.body.setHomePage('http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com');

}

//Condition to set home page in Mozilla

else if (window.sidebar) {

if (window.netscape) {

try {

netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");

}

catch (e) {

}

}

var prefs = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/preferences-

service;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);

prefs.setCharPref('browser.startup.homepage', 'http://www.google.com');

}

}